# Will conditional ads hurt my page rank or "confuse" web crawlers

Tags: php, seo, adsense, pagerank

At http://hollywoodnose.com I have conditional ads based on how many images there are for each page.  So if there's one image I'll have a 468 x 60.  If there's 4 images I'll have a 180 x 150 text ad appear after the 2nd image and a 336 x 180 appear below all 4.  This goes on for 13 different conditions;  depending if there's 1 image, 2 images, 3 images, etc.  Will this "annoy" the crawlers in turn hurting my page rank?

You can see what I mean http://hollywoodnose.com/TomCruiseNoseJob.  Just brows random pages and you'll see how the ad layout changes for how many images there area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, crawlers only hate it when you point to the *exact same page* from hundreds of different URLs. This happens with dropdown menus and tagging systems usually. As an aside, just try and make sure you have proper `alt` text for all ads and images.

Comment: Thanks, and I definitely do.  Like 80% of my traffic is from alt text.  Probably one of the most powerful and often overlooked ways of getting traffic.